# Endless loop with wp_insert_post and wp_update_post

Tags: loop, wp-insert-post, php, wp-update-post

I have an array `$unqiues` which contains URL's, I loop over the array with the code below to get the URL titles, insert a new post, update the post meta. Then I change the the posts title and name to the $pid which was returned by wp_insert_post.

This created an endless loop, I have about 600 or fewer URL's in the $unique array. I just hit 75,000 queries within an hour on my host and have to wait an hour for the limit to reset. What caused the endless loop? This code worked when I tested with 10 URL's in the array.

How can this be written more efficiently?

Thanks

```
foreach($uniques as $unique){
      $pagetitle = getTitle($unique);
      $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $unique,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'websites'
        );
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        update_post_meta($pid,'title', $pagetitle);
        update_post_meta($pid,'url',$unique);


          $my_post = array(
              'ID'           => $pid,
              'post_title' => $pid,
              'post_name' => $pid
          );

          wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

Comment: How do you run that code? What is the context?

Comment: @s_ha_dum It fires within a `if (isset($_POST['submit'])` conditional

Comment: @Anagio in which file? Is this code wrapped in a function? if so, this function hook into some action?

Comment: @G.M. this is outside the loop i've included wp-blog-header.php it's not hooking into any action or filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure can be written in a more efficient way (untested):

```
$added = array();
global $wpdb;
foreach($uniques as $unique){
  $pagetitle = getTitle($unique);
  $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $unique,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'websites'
  );
  $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
  if ($pid) {
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES
       (%d, '%s', '%s'), (%d, '%s', '%s')",
       $pid, 'title', $pagetitle, $pid, 'url', $unique
    ) );
    $added[] = $pid;
  }
}
if ( ! empty($added) ) {
   $ids = implode(',', $added); 
   $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET `post_title` = `ID`, `post_name` = `ID` WHERE `ID` IN ($ids)");
}
```

With 600 urls this code runs 1200 queries less than your, but maybe is not enough...

Comment: Thanks but why use $wpdb when I have WordPress functions available?

Comment: See the last $wpdb query. Do in 1 query what using WP function you do in 600 queries. 599 queries less. The first $wpdb query do in 1 query what you do in 2. 1 query less x 600 urls = 600 queries less. Also consider that WP functions fire filter and action and if you have plugins/theme that hooks in this actions you will run additional (maybe slow) code...

Comment: @Anagio I forget to tag you in previous comment. Note also that I have the suspect that some code (plugin/theme) are hooking into `save_post` action, that is triggered by both `wp_insert_post` and `wp_update_post`. If I'm right, you are running that code 1200 times...

Comment: I'll reply once I test it, it may not be tonight though tomorrow for sure

Comment: You are welcome. Have you seen if there are any function hookin 'save_post' action? To speed up loading and exxluding plugin can also try to define 'SHORTINIT' constant before bootstrapping wordpress.

Comment: Hi G.M. no I haven't checked if any plugins have actions or filters on those functions. But while testing today there seems to be a bug where duplicate posts are created, then for each new post it runs the `$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare` function all over again and doesn't stop. I'm going to test printing arrays throughout the code and will post a new question. Thanks again